# Using preg_match on a URL with a query string

Tags: javascript, regex

I want find all URLs that match with a given URL.

When I try the code below with this URL:

```
$url_regex = '^http://toilatester.com/category/?xv=.*'; 

$urls = array( 
    'http://toilatester.com/category/?xv=123333/time1-one1', 
    'http://toilatester.com/category/?xv=78787878/time1-one1', 
    'http://toilatester.com/category/?xv=78547547/time1-one1' 
);

foreach ($urls as $urllink) { 
    if (preg_match($url_regex, $urllink, $a)) { 
        $arr_link[] = $a[0]; 
    } 
} 
die(print_r($arr_link));
```

It does not match as expected.

If I change `$url_regex` to ^http://toilatester.com/category/.* then it works, but I need begin with `http://toilatester.com/category/?xv=`.

I think the problem is the special character **?**

Please help? 
Thank you

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php

Comment: In particular the resource above says: The special regular expression characters are: . \ + * ? [ ^ ] $ ( ) { } = ! < > | : -

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the **?** character has a special meaning in a regex.
To match the question mark, you need to escape it in the regex like:

```
$url_regex = '^http://toilatester.com/category/\?xv=.*';
```